# Error: cannot find symbol - class 'Date' (Java/NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a rookie programer, I have this problem with java using Netbeans and not found solution :c

[image]

Comment: `import java.util.Date;`, see [Using Package Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) for more details.  While you're at it, take a look at the [Date/Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) trail and make use of the new date/time API instead of `Date`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the right library above your code
`import java.util.Date;`